# How to get the latest .tga file by date in subfolders using glob?

Tags: python

I need help to find how to get the latest `.tga` file in severals subfolders (I don't know how much, because it's variable). I only know how to do in just one subfolder:

```
opath = '{0}\\EP{1}\\05_FinalAni\\{2}\\{3}\\COMP\\'.format(
            prj_base_path, episode, seq, beforeShot).replace('\\', '/')
for file in glob.glob(opathBefore + '*/*.tga'):
    newest = max(glob.iglob(opathBefore + '*/*.tga'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: What is `opathBefore`? Does it end with a `/`? You should join path elements together with `os.path.join()` not string concatenation. To find the latest file in multiple subfolders, you either need to first create a list of them all, or use something like `os.path.walk()` and keep track of the newest one seen as the folder structure gets traversed. You can match filenames using `fnmatch`, which is how `glob` does it.

Comment: Gnn: If you clean up your question, I could provide you with a proper answer.

Comment: thanks martineau, for the variable path, this was an error, in fact opathBefore = opath... and for os.path.walk() i can't find how to use it with max and key=os.path.getctime.... is there another way to find the last date with os?

Comment: opath = '{0}\\EP{1}\\05_FinalAni\\{2}\\{3}\\COMP\\'.format(
            prj_base_path, episode, seq, beforeShot).replace('\\', '/')
for file in glob.glob(opath + '*/*.tga'):
    newest = max(glob.iglob(opathBefore + '*/*.tga'), key=os.path.getctime)

Comment: For `os.path.walk()` you should be able to just compare the timestamp of each file in each directory processed to the value in a separate variable that you're using to keep track of what the timestamp was of the most recent file that has been seen so far. After traversing all the subfolders, the final value of that variable will be that of the latest (newest) file seen. You don't need `max()` to compare the timestamps (although I suppose you could do it that inefficient way).

Comment: do you mean with os.path.getmtime(path) ?

Comment: Yes, if `path` is the path of a `.tga` file. Please don't ask me for any more help here in the comments section...especially if you're not going to [edit] your question and improve it.

Comment: it's ok, sorry and thanks a lot for your answer